# Join two tables and display images in array based on id in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I am trying to join 2 tables based on the id. I want to display the second table images to be displayed together in a single array
art_column {
id  :   66
name    :   Test2
title   :   Art 2
image   :   null
art_work :      {Penguins.jpg},{Tulips.jpg}
}

Table artcolumn stores id,name,image,title
Table artwork_images store a_id,art_work
Joining id and a_id i get the data but how can i store in array in the given format

Here is the code

```
    $result = ("SELECT artcolumn.id,title, image,name,art_work FROM artcolumn JOIN               artwork_images ON artwork_images.a_id = artcolumn.id") or die(mysqli_error());
    $sql=mysqli_query($con,$result);

if (mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0) {
    // looping through all results items node
    $response["artcolumn"] = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        // temp user array
        $news = array();
        $news["id"] = $row["id"];
       
       
        $news["name"] = $row["name"];
            $news["title"] = $row["title"];
         $news["image"] = $row["image"];
        
       $news["art_work"] = $row["art_work"];
     
        array_push($response["artcolumn"], $news);
 
    }
```

In my code id,name,title,images get repeated for second image also

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = 'SELECT artcolumn.id, title, image, name, art_work' .
    ' FROM artcolumn' .
    ' JOIN artwork_images ON artwork_images.a_id = artcolumn.id';
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error());

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // looping through all results items node
    $response["artcolumn"] = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        if (array_key_exists($row['id'], $response['artcolumn'])) {
            $response['artcolumn'][$row['id']]['art_work'][] = [$row['art_work']];
        } else {
            $response['artcolumn'][$row['id']] = [
                'id' => $row['id'],
                'title' => $row['title'],
                'image' => $row['image'],
                'name' => $row['name'],
                'art_work' => [[$row['art_work']]],
            ];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But i  want art_work as separate array art_work:{penguins.jpg},{tulips.jpg}.It is displaying as art_work {penguin.jpg,tulips.jpg} now

Comment: You want each element in its own array?

Comment: OK I adjusted the answer